# QueryException: could not resolve property: catId of: com.my.myquiz.entity.Question

Tags: spring-boot, jpa, spring-data-jpa, many-to-one

I have created simple Quiz using Spring data and I have mapped Question and Category in **Many to One** relationship using annotations. I am queering to get random question under a given category, But it gives above error and I tried few alternatives. But not working it seems.

**Category.java**

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "categories")
public class Category {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private long catId;

    @Column(nullable = false , unique = true)
    private String description;
```

**Question.java**

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "question")
public class Question {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private long questionId;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "catId", nullable = false, updatable = false)
    @JsonBackReference
    private Category category;

    @Lob
    @Column (nullable = false)
    private String question;

    @Column (nullable = false)
    private String medium;
```

**QuestionRepository.java**

```
@Repository
@Transactional
public interface QuestionRepository extends JpaRepository<Question, Long> {

    @Query("select question from Question question where question.catId = :catId AND question.medium = :medium order by function('RAND')")
    List<Question> getQuestionsForAttempt(@Param("catId") Long catId , @Param("medium") String medium);

    @Query("select question from Question  question where question.catId = : catId")
    List<Question> getQuestionByCategory(@Param("catId") Long catId);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is JPQL not SQL so you have to go thought the dependencies in your query:

```
select question from Question  question where question.category.catId
```

or

```
select question from Question  question  inner join question.category c where c.catId
```